# Tomcat+Wicket: a lot of ThreadContext warnings when stopping tomcat

Tags: tomcat, wicket

When stopping Tomcat running our Wicket-6.19-based website a lof of warnings flood our log files:

```
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 06, 2015 8:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
...
Jul 06, 2015 8:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@581d6d]) and a value of type [org.apache.wicket.ThreadContext] (value [org.apache.wicket.ThreadContext@f40228]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
...
```

Is this a problem I should care about? Could this be a problem in how we are using Wicket?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a thread dump and check what these blocked request are doing.

I doubt that Wicket is causing these threads to hang.